# Никто нам не указ

Tags: синтаксис

*Никто нам не указ*.

Чем здесь выражено сказуемое?

Comment: А Ваше-то какое мнение на этот счёт?

Comment: "не указ"?.. tipo: "нам никто не есть указ"... но очень очень сомнения есть : (

Comment: Правильно, "не указ".  Теперь надо понять, что за вид сказуемого.

Comment: Victooooor, не мучайтеее!!! : ) у меня супер супер маленькие знания русской грамматики!

Comment: Ну, раз маленькие, то и надо их потихонечку, как курочка - по зёрнышку...  Какая часть речи основная в "не указ"?

Comment: Видов сказуемых всего три...

Comment: если "указ" это существительное, может это именное?

Comment: Тагирикс уже Вам всё испортил, сделав за Вас Ваше задание...  {sigh}

Comment: : ) он ничего не испортил, он меня спас!!! у меня уже были ооочень печальные глаза =) всем спасибо!!!

Comment: Русские говорили: "Бог спасает того, кто спасается сам".  Арабы говорят: "На тагирикса надейся, а верблюда ***привязывай***".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В предложении *никто нам не указ* сказуемое выражено именем существительным (***не указ***). Если же дано предложение (это вы в комментариях написали) *нам никто не есть указ*, то здесь, я думаю, сказуемое будет иметь следующий вид: ***не есть указ***. По грамматике оба сказуемых друг от друга не отличаются, оба относятся к СИС (составное именное сказуемое).